# How to calculate new variables in a data frame with multiple row-length?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, dplyr, apply

I have the following data.frame (df) consists of different user per product purchase probabilities.

```
   ID    P1    P2    P3    P4    P5    P6    P7    P8    P9    P10
1  1     .1    .2    .1    .5    .8    NA    NA    .7    .4    NA 
2  2     .4    NA    NA    .3    .7    .8    NA    .5    .8    NA 
3  3     .3    .1    NA    .9    NA    .5    .1    .2    .1    .1 
4  4     .5    NA    NA    NA    NA    .5    .1    NA    NA    .1
```

During my analysis I have classified different product categories. 
 
For example P2,P3,P4 and P5 are related to CLASS1. 
 
**EXPECTED OUTPUT:** I would like to calculate different means per user per product category.

My problem is now, that there are some users (for example here user4) without any probability in the specified class. That's why my output of calculation has less rows than my dataframe.

I'm looking for an elegant way to code this problem efficient.

I have tried it like this and get an error because of different length of my df and my new variable

```
df$class1 <- rowMeans(filter(df[,3:6], df$P2 > 0 | df$P3 > 0 | df$P4 > 0 | df$P5 > 0), na.rm=T)
```

Comment: `filter` is meant for time series, maybe you want `subset`? Note, however, that all the entries in your df are greater than zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, P1 = c(0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.5), P2 = c(0.2, 
NA, 0.1, NA), P3 = c(0.1, NA, NA, NA), P4 = c(0.5, 0.3, 0.9, 
NA), P5 = c(0.8, 0.7, NA, NA), P6 = c(NA, 0.8, 0.5, 0.5), P7 = c(NA, 
NA, 0.1, 0.1), P8 = c(0.7, 0.5, 0.2, NA), P9 = c(0.4, 0.8, 0.1, 
NA), P10 = c(NA, NA, 0.1, 0.1)), .Names = c("ID", "P1", "P2", 
"P3", "P4", "P5", "P6", "P7", "P8", "P9", "P10"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

#### solution

```
df$class1 <- rowMeans(df[,3:6], na.rm=T)
```

#### output

```
   ID  P1  P2  P3  P4  P5  P6  P7  P8  P9 P10 class1
1:  1 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.5 0.8  NA  NA 0.7 0.4  NA    0.4
2:  2 0.4  NA  NA 0.3 0.7 0.8  NA 0.5 0.8  NA    0.5
3:  3 0.3 0.1  NA 0.9  NA 0.5 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.1    0.5
4:  4 0.5  NA  NA  NA  NA 0.5 0.1  NA  NA 0.1    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly this would be the dplyr way:

```
library(dplyr)
test <- data.frame(P1 = c(0.1, NA, NA), P2 = c(NA, 0.2, 0.3), P3 = c(0.4, 0.5, NA))
test <- test %>% mutate(meanA = rowMeans(select(., P1, P2, P3), na.rm = T))
```